# checkbox with Inkwell

Tags: flutter, dart

I had working `CheckboxListTile` but i changed it to `Checkbox` to remove its spacing between `Checkbox` and `Text`. I wrapped it with `Inkwell`.
My problem is i am not being able to get `value` of `onChange:(bool? value)` of `checkbox` which i need use it `onTap` method of `Inkwell`.
below is code of `onChange` of checkbox and i want it to use it in `onTap` method of `Inkwell`. Please suggest how to do do this.

```
onChanged: (bool? value) {
                if (_allSelectedItems.length == correctAnswerList.length) {
                  myGroupValue = value ?? myGroupValue;
                  for (int i = 0; i < _allSelectedItems.length; i++) {
                    if (optionLength[index] == _allSelectedItems[i]) {
                      setState(() {
                        _allSelectedItems.remove(_allSelectedItems[i]);
                      });
                    }
                  }


                } else {
                  _selectedAnswers.clear();
                  myGroupValue = value ?? myGroupValue;

                  if (value == false) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _allSelectedItems.length; i++) {
                      if (optionLength[index] == _allSelectedItems[i]) {
                        _allSelectedItems.remove(_allSelectedItems[i]);
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    _allSelectedItems.add(optionLength[index]);
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                }

                _initialList = _allSelectedItems;

                print(_initialList.length);
                
                _selectedAnswers.clear();
                for (var element in _allSelectedItems) {
                  _selectedAnswers.add(element);
                }
              },
```

`CheckboxListTile`

```
SizedBox(
                                                width:
                                                    getWidth(screenWidth, 6.5),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            left: 0.0),
                                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                                        itemCount:
                                                            optionLength.length,
                                                        itemBuilder:
                                                            (BuildContext
                                                                    context,
                                                                index) {
                                                          List<String>
                                                              listValues =
                                                              List.from(mySnapshot
                                                                          .docs[
                                                                      _counter
                                                                          .value]
                                                                  ['options']);

                                                          bool? myGroupValue =
                                                              checkSelected4CheckBox(
                                                                  mySnapshot,
                                                                  index);

                                                          List<String>
                                                              correctAnswerList =
                                                              List.from(mySnapshot
                                                                          .docs[
                                                                      _counter
                                                                          .value]
                                                                  [
                                                                  'correctAnswers']);

                                                          List selectedAnswers =
                                                              List.from(mySnapshot
                                                                          .docs[
                                                                      _counter
                                                                          .value]
                                                                  [
                                                                  'selectedAnswers']);

                                                          List
                                                              tempSelectedList =
                                                              List.from(mySnapshot
                                                                          .docs[
                                                                      _counter
                                                                          .value]
                                                                  [
                                                                  'selectedAnswers']);

                                                         
                                                          return StatefulBuilder(
                                                              builder: (
                                                            BuildContext
                                                                context,
                                                            StateSetter
                                                                setState,
                                                          ) {
                                                            return
                                                               
                                                                Padding(
                                                              padding:
                                                                  const EdgeInsets
                                                                          .only(
                                                                      left: 8.0,
                                                                      top: 0,
                                                                      bottom:
                                                                          0),
                                                              child: Transform
                                                                  .translate(
                                                                offset:
                                                                    const Offset(
                                                                        -16, 0),
                                                                child:
                                                                    CheckboxListTile(
                                                                  visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                                                      horizontal:
                                                                          VisualDensity
                                                                              .minimumDensity,
                                                                      vertical:
                                                                          VisualDensity
                                                                              .minimumDensity),
                                                                  //  selected: true,
                                                                  value:
                                                                      myGroupValue,
                                                                  controlAffinity:
                                                                      ListTileControlAffinity
                                                                          .leading,
                                                                  // selected: checkSelected4CheckBox(mySnapshot, index),
                                                                  dense: true,
                                                                  title: Transform
                                                                      .translate(
                                                                    offset:
                                                                        const Offset(
                                                                            -16,
                                                                            0),
                                                                    child: Text(
                                                                      listValues[
                                                                          index],
                                                                      style: Theme.of(
                                                                              context)
                                                                          .textTheme
                                                                          .bodySmall,

                                                                      //* to change Text color according to the selected use below
                                                                      // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                                                                      //       color: (e == myGroupValue) ? containerHeader : radioUnSelectedColor,
                                                                      //     ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),

                                                                  onChanged:
                                                                      (bool?
                                                                          value) {
                                                         
                                                                    if (_allSelectedItems
                                                                            .length ==
                                                                        correctAnswerList
                                                                            .length) {
                                                                      myGroupValue =
                                                                          value ??
                                                                              myGroupValue;
                                                                      for (int i =
                                                                              0;
                                                                          i < _allSelectedItems.length;
                                                                          i++) {
                                                                        if (optionLength[index] ==
                                                                            _allSelectedItems[i]) {
                                                                          setState(
                                                                              () {
                                                                            _allSelectedItems.remove(_allSelectedItems[i]);
                                                                          });
                                                                        }
                                                                      }
                                                         
                                                                    } else {
                                                                      _selectedAnswers
                                                                          .clear();
                                                                      myGroupValue =
                                                                          value ??
                                                                              myGroupValue;

                                                                      if (value ==
                                                                          false) {
                                                                        for (int i =
                                                                                0;
                                                                            i < _allSelectedItems.length;
                                                                            i++) {
                                                                          if (optionLength[index] ==
                                                                              _allSelectedItems[i]) {
                                                                            _allSelectedItems.remove(_allSelectedItems[i]);
                                                                          }
                                                                        }
                                                                      } else {
                                                         
                                                                        _allSelectedItems
                                                                            .add(optionLength[index]);
                                                                      }
                                                                      setState(
                                                                          () {});
                                                                    }

                                                                    _initialList =
                                                                        _allSelectedItems;
                                                                                                                             print(_initialList
                                                                        .length);
                                                                    _selectedAnswers
                                                                        .clear();
                                                                    for (var element
                                                                        in _allSelectedItems) {
                                                                      _selectedAnswers
                                                                          .add(
                                                                              element);
                                                                    }
                                                                  },
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            );

                                                           
                                                          });
                                                        })),
                                              ),
```

Comment: could you please give me CheckboxListTile widget details in here.

Comment: @Babul please check my code for `CheckboxListTile`. i tried my best to remove the spacing between Checkbox and Text but still i am not satisfied. Please suggest me how to improve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `Checkbox` into an [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) to passthrough tappings in the checkbox to the parent `InkWell`. Then ignore completely the `Checkbox.onChange` event and use the state itself as the checkbox value.

Check it out (Also [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=dcd4b0108c6128cd27935fd1ef064d56))

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const checkboxCount = 4;
  final checkboxValue = <int, bool>{};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 120,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              for (var i = 0; i < checkboxCount; i++)
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => setState(
                      () => checkboxValue[i] = !(checkboxValue[i] ?? false)),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        IgnorePointer(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 16,
                            width: 32,
                            child: Checkbox(
                              checkColor: Colors.black,
                              value: checkboxValue[i] ?? false,
                              onChanged: (_) {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text('Checkbox ${i + 1}'),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply . i tried your method,it doesn't work on my current widget context . But it worked pretty well on Radio button.Thanks